# Blue-green deployment for Jenkins itself

Tags: jenkins, blue-green-deployment

When I tinker with my live Jenkins instance, I risk down time.  Thus I want to run blue and green Jenkins master instances.  This way, I can work on one while the other is live and stable.

As expected, searching on this topic tells me how to use Jenkins to do blue-green deployment of *other* applications.

Do you have any tips or references to give me a head start on setting up green and blue Jenkins masters?

Comment: Good question, but it would probably be better suited to Server Fault.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I [posted the question](http://serverfault.com/questions/706392/blue-green-deployment-for-jenkins-itself) there too.